# Identify Data File Line Number in Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load data using BULK insert and I am able load data into Azure SQL Server for fewer rows. I know there is error/format issue in the data file but my file contains millions of records so, its very hard for me to test the data chunk by chunk. I am pulling data from BLOB storage is there any way to find out the exact file line number that's causing the below issue.

**Error:**

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

**Code:**

```
BULK INSERT a.test
FROM 'cc'
WITH (
   DATA_SOURCE = 'Test'
  --, FORMAT = 'CSV'
  --,ROWS_PER_BATCH=1000000
 ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
 ,ROWTERMINATOR = '|'
 ,MAXERRORS = 10000
 )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the errorfile argument to dump out the rows that are not parsing/inserting into another file.  This should help reduce the problem to something more manageable.

Please read the reference here - it works on more recent versions of SQL Server (2017+).  it should also work on SQL Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have already tried that option but getting an error. I added following code  ERRORFILE ='https://test.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx/aaa'  Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Cannot bulk load because the file "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx/aaa" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Cannot bulk load because the file "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx/aaa.Error.Txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).

Comment: perhaps trying against a local copy of SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.2 will give you a bit more control over the test until we can narrow it down?  the bulk insert code should be the same, though the hosting environment in SQL Azure is more locked down and may not be running under the same permission scheme that you have in SQL Server.  (If it ends up being a bug I can ask the team to go fix once we have a sense where it is breaking)

Comment: It looks like a bug for me because the path is correct and the file exists over there and I don't know why its throwing this error. If we fix this issue in the default error message then it will be more helpful. Default error message is not helpful at all to find the RCA of this problem